# preg_match first string after string in parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, phpcodesniffer

I've looked around for solutions close to this but have not been successful in finding a solution. I'm looking to clean up some legacy code via php_codesniffer but the fixer doesn't fix comments or arrays that go past 80 cols just lets you know about them. I have a solution that works for the comments but I am getting stuck on the regex for the arrays.
A sample line I would like to fix is:

```
$line = "drupal_add_js(array('my_common' => array('my_code_validate' => variable_get('my_code_validate', FALSE), 'inner_index2 => 'inner_value2'), 'another_item' => 'another_value'), 'setting');";
$solution = preg_match('/array.*(\(.*?\))/', $line);
echo $solution;
```

I'd like

```
$solution  = "'my_common' => array('my_code_validate' => variable_get('my_code_validate', FALSE), 'inner_index2 => 'inner_value2'), 'another_item' => 'another_value'";
```

but I am getting 1 instead. Notice that there is another array in there which is fairly common. I only want to capture the first array's values, and then I can split them up on separate lines from there. Ultimately I'd like to share my solutions to the php codesniffer project so bonus points for showing how to code a new fixer for squizlabs.

Comment: is the last thing in the string always the word `'setting'`?

Comment: `preg_match` just returns the number of matches. you need to add the third parameter to get the actual match text. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Try `preg_match('~array(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))~', $s, $matches)` and grab `$matches[2]`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/HQ52zX/1).

Comment: @Ibrahim No, setting is tied to the drupal_add_js bit, I'm just trying to get the array inside there. And this is just an example, there are literally thousands of lines that need to be fixed and they are all different.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that looks like it works exactly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
if (preg_match('~array(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))~', $s, $matches)) {
  echo $matches[2];
}
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/HQ52zX/1).

**Details**

- `array` - a literal substring
- `(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))` - Group 1:

  - `\(`
  - `((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)` - Group 2 (the required value):

    - `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` - zero or more repetitions of 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` or the whole Group 1 pattern recursed
  - `\)` - a `)` char

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
.*?array\(('.*?)\), [^\)]+'\);.*
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oV4nvT/4/